# Upload multiple file at once php html

Tags: php, html

Can someone help me to make my code more simple and effective ? srry i'm just a newbie. I'm trying to upload multiple file at once but the action just take one upload. Pls fix my code thx

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="fileSelect" multiple="multiple"><?php echo $photo_err;?><br><br>
<input type="file" name="photo2" id="fileSelect" multiple="multiple"><?php echo $photo_err;?><br><br>

if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
    $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    // Verify file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) 
        die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

    // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
    $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    if($filesize > $maxsize) 
        die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

    // Verify MYME type of the file
    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){            
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);            
    } else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
    }
} 
// No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
if($_FILES['photo']['size'] == 0) 
{ 
    $photo_err = "Please Select an Image.";
}
```

Also

```
if(isset($_FILES["photo2"]) && $_FILES["photo2"]["error"] == 0){
    $allowed2 = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
    $filename2 = $_FILES["photo2"]["name"];
    $filetype2 = $_FILES["photo2"]["type"];
    $filesize2 = $_FILES["photo2"]["size"];
    $temp2 = explode(".", $_FILES["photo2"]["name"]);
    $newfilename2 = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp2);
    // Verify file extension
    $ext2 = pathinfo($filename2, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext2, $allowed2)) 
        die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

    // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
    $maxsize2 = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    if($filesize2 > $maxsize2) 
        die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

    // Verify MYME type of the file
    if(in_array($filetype2, $allowed2)){            
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo2"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename2);            
    } else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
    }
} 
// No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
if($_FILES['photo2']['size'] == 0) 
{ 
    $photo_err2 = "Please Select an Image.";
}
```

Any help will be grateful.Thx

Comment: You should read the manual about multiple uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php Btw, both fields have the same id. That's not valid. id's must be unique within the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you looking for

```
    <?php
    define( 'MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE', 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5Mo
    define( 'UPLOAD_PATH', 'upload' );

    function is_allowed_file_ext( $filename = null )
    {
        $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
        $_parts = explode( '.', $filename );
        $_ext = end( $_parts );
        $_ext = strtolower( $_ext );
        if( in_array( $_ext , $allowed_ext ) ){
            return $_ext;
        }
        return false;
    }

    if( !empty( $_FILES['photo'] ) ){
        foreach ($_FILES['photo']['name'] as $key => $filename ) {
            if( $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

                if( $file_ext = is_allowed_file_ext( $filename ) ){
                    $new_filename = sprintf( '%d-%s.%s', round(microtime(true)), uniqid(), $file_ext );
                    if( $_FILES['photo']['size'][$key] <= MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE ){
                        // Everything is okay now, save the file
                        $dest_path = sprintf( '%s/%s', rtrim(UPLOAD_PATH,'/'), $new_filename );
                        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key], $dest_path );
                    }else{
                        $photo_errors[] = 'Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.';
                    }
                }else{
                    $photo_errors[] = $filename . ' is not a valid image';
                }
            }else{
                switch ( $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key] ) {
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                        $photo_errors[] = 'No file sent';
                        break;
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                        $photo_errors[] = 'Max file size exceeded!';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $photo_errors[] = 'Unknown errors';
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        $photo_errors[] = 'No photos selected';
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="photo[]" id="fileSelect" multiple="multiple">
        <?php foreach ($photo_errors as $photo_error):?>
            <div class="photo-error"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $photo_error ); ?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: this code work good. Thx for your help

Comment: if u can help me again, how i separate the $new_filename so i can put it into database with different column. Thx